# Willl a file or folder be visible or detectable to other users if I set its mod to 700?

Tags: filesystems

As in the title, I need to make one of my folder not visible to others, I am thinking about making it to be 700. Will this work to make other people not see my folder ?

If not, apart from renaming it to be `.file`, how could I make my folder not visible or detectable to other users?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the parent directory is readable AND traversable `r-x`, any file or directory contained (including "hidden" ones using `ls -a`) can be seen to be existing.

However, if the file or directory itself does not have any permission for the user traversing there, its contents cannot be read.

Example:
`/root` typically has `r-xr-x---` or `rwxr-x---`

Everyone can see that `/root` exists, but only root can traverse into it and read its contents.

Side note: For files I would not recommend to apply permissions 700 (`rwx------`) unless it is a script or binary.  Ordinary files should instead have 600 (`rw-------`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the file or folder will be visible to other users.  Permissions on a file or folder control the information about the object that users can see, but not is existence.

For example on my system I have a user called 'test'.  As my normal user 'neek' I create a file and chmod it:

```
$ cat > ~/some-file
hello
^D
$ chmod 700 ~/some-file
```

Now su to `test` user and stat the file:

```
$ stat /home/neek/some-file
  File: /home/neek/some-file
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 812h/2066d      Inode: 6649290     Links: 1
Access: (0700/-rwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/    neek)   Gid: ( 1000/    neek)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2019-10-21 11:41:02.947116946 +0700
Modify: 2019-10-21 11:41:02.947116946 +0700
Change: 2019-10-21 11:41:05.963103029 +0700
 Birth: 2019-10-21 11:41:02.947116946 +0700
```

But, I cannot see its contents:

```
$ cat /home/neek/some-file
cat: /home/neek/some-file: Permission denied
```

Making the file 'hidden' by prepending the filename with a dot `.` is no guarantee of invisibility, as it is easily got around with `ls -a` or 'Show Hidden Files' in your file browser.  It's 'security by obscurity'.

Directories use the 'x' permission to control traversal across the directory, and 'r' to control reading its contents.  But before I spend any more time...

Your question seems more targeted at making a file or folder completely invisible to other users, which I believe cannot be done with a normal installation though I am no expert on file systems.

I would suggest using an encrypted partition, or filesystem-in-a-file, for example a quick search led me to https://www.tecmint.com/cryptmount-create-encrypted-filesystems-in-linux/ which mentions 'loopback file' which would mean the file system is contained in a single normal file on your filesystem, and can be mounted at some mount point of your choosing, similar to how mounting a .iso file works, but since its contents is encypted no-one would be able to see its contents without authentication.